# Is there any way to disable specific push notifications for an Android app?

Tags: android

I'm coding an Android app which will have a configuration settings screen.
user might disable/enable specific push notifications - there will be several kinds of notifications coming from Amazon SNS Queue (some notifications will be from marketing department, other ones from human resources department, and so on)

Would it be possible to enable a push to receive notifications from human resources and disable from marketing? I mean... would there be any way that Android application may detect a 'specific' push from some department and may show it... and may detect a 'specific' push from another department and may not show it?

I mean an 'intelligence' contained in Android application code itself. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can send keys/values with the Push message and when that is received, determine whether you want to send a notification.

A better way to do it is to save these settings on the server so that the server knows which notifications to send to which user/device-id

Comment: It means a reduce on your costs as well once you won't be sending unnecessary pushes

Comment: Thanks @Sheikh Aman, I do agree with you regarding saving these settings on the server, but for some reason I could not provide further details, IT security team in our company does not let these info to be saved into a server.

Comment: I do agree with you also, @VictorNeves, but not an option from mine. Due to decision of another ones above me, storing such info in servers is not an option.

Comment: well when the application receives the otification through a broadcast maybe you could store the users information of department in the phone location in a file and have the app read the file and check against the incoming notification before displaying the notification.